# What does David mean by soul?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-covenant

In Alien:Covenant,

> David replies "Well, well, well. So many good souls." When he is informed that there are 2,000 colonists on the Covenant.

We learn later that

> David uses the colonists as hosts/food for the aliens.

What concept of the soul underlies the Alien movies?  And how does that concept of a soul relate to what happens when an alien takes over a human.  And is this concept similar across all the Alien franchise movies?

Later in the film, when asked what he believes in, David replied :

> Creation.

Comment: Are you asking what David meant (which I think is answered below), or about which concept of the soul underlies the Alien movies, which I think is unanswerable?

Comment: some people think the earth’s flat too! (Which, incidentally, is for many purposes a perfectly reasonable simplification.) But the one Alien movie to mention memory transfer doesn’t mention souls.

Answer (score 4):

From [Wiktionary:](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/soul#English)

> **soul** (plural **souls**)
>
> 5. A person, especially as one among many.
>
> "I want to gather together about twenty souls and sail away from this world of war and squalor and found a little colony where there shall be no money but a sort of communism as far as necessaries of life go, and some real decency." - D. H. Lawrence
>
> 6. An individual life.
>
> "Fifty souls were lost when the ship sank."

He's not talking metaphysically.  It's just a colourful way of saying "people".

Comment: Your response does not explain why you choose this definition instead of others.  However, your response is not out of alignment with David's formal, classical European demeanor.

Comment: None of the other definitions really fit with the way the context and the way the sentence is phrased.  (For one thing, if he was referring to their literal souls, he would be unlikely to describe them as "good" without at least some evidence to that effect.  Even then it would be an odd thing to say outside of an explicitly religious context.)